# Linux: a C++ library fails to link after recompiling

Tags: c++, linker, googletest

I had a https://github.com/simongog/sdsl-lite library installed on a remote Linux server. What I did was to create `lib`, `include` directories inside my home directory and then run the script as `./install.sh /my/home/dir`, as indeed explained on the above page. I was able to do it once and successfully linked it to my other programs by using a `CMakeLists.txt` file as the one similar to the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

macro(use_cxx14)
  if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.1")
    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
        set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -O2 -mcmodel=large")
    endif ()
  else ()
     set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
  endif ()
endmacro(use_cxx14)

use_cxx14()

# Locate GTest
link_directories(/my/home/dir/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} /my/home/dir/)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/my/home/dir/")
list(APPEND CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH /my/home/dir/lib/)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/my/home/dir/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/my/home/dir/lib)
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(runTests rs_bitvector_test.cpp)
# SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
# SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
# SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
target_link_libraries(runTests sdsl ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

(the server was missing C++14 but the name remains, although really I use the C++11 option)

Now I've changed a source file inside the previously downloaded location of the library and recompiled it. And now linking stopped working. What could be the reason? During re-compilation, the remote server kept telling me about some "modification time in the future" and "build may be incomplete". Is that the reason? What can be done?

EDIT: based off the suggestions in the comments, I removed the `build` directory (analog of `make clean`) and replaced it with that from the directory of the original bundle. Now, the timstamps issue is gone, but the linking still fails.

Comment: You (or somebody) did something that caused at least one file in the build tree to have a timestamp
that was (invalidly) in the future, by the server's clock, when it
ran the build. Since Make compares the timestamps of targets and
prerequisites to know what it should build, the build is corrupt. Try
fixing it by `make clean`. Or if CMake does not provide a `clean` target, then delete the CMake build directory and start again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily, after noticing that `sdsl` detected `g++ 7.3` during installation while `cmake` was compiling using `4.8`, I used https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F to set the compiler to `g++ 7.3` (using Method 3 in the above link), and it finally worked (still some issues with GTest, but it is OK).